# Why does Windows make us specify size of structures in some api?

Tags: windows, winapi

In some windows APIs, for example `Module32Next`, `Module32First`, `Process32Next`, `Thread32Next`, etc, programmers are forced to set the `dwSize` field of structure to the size of the structure. Why does Windows make us do that? Isn't these structures defined by Windows itself? Isn't the size a known constant?

PS: I looked into these functions and found that they just check if the size is equal to a hard coded constant.

Comment: The size might vary from one version to another.

Comment: [Why are structure sizes checked strictly?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031212-00/?p=41523)

Comment: How would you know, whether it is a [BITMAPINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183375.aspx) structure, or a [BITMAPCOREINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183373.aspx) structure, following the [BITMAPFILEHEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374.aspx), if those structures didn't specify their sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official info about Thread32First function [says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686728(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Thread32First changes dwSize to the number of bytes written to the
>   structure. This will never be greater than the initial value of
>   dwSize, but it may be smaller. If the value is smaller, do not rely on
>   the values of any members whose offsets are greater than this value.

I understand that, by specifying a value in `dwSize`, we tell Windows we don't need the other *"members whose offsets are greater than this value"*.

(edited) After some tests, I believe now the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38931344/6037365) is that from Harry Johnston's.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say you can do that.  (I'm not absolutely certain that it won't work for those particular functions, but it [certainly doesn't in the general case](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031212-00/?p=41523).)

Comment: @Harry Johnston: You're dead right. I just did some tests trying out different values in `dwSize` and all failed except when assigning `dwSize` the full size of the structure `THREADENTRY32`, that is (in Delphi): `dwSize := SizeOf(TThreadEntry32);`

Answer (score 4):

By requiring the programmer to specify the size of the structure, Windows can tell which version of the structure the programmer is using.  Some such structures have actually changed between different versions of Windows, and some haven't - but providing the size means that Microsoft have the option of changing it if they need to, without breaking existing applications.

Comment: Since it was one of the APIs you mentioned, it should be noted that Thread32First() is a special case, in that it also *returns* a value in that field.  As far as I know this is the only function that does so.  I have no idea why!